# Array: check an element and the following element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, element

when i got an Array `a` and i want to modify an element and the element that comes after that? So there are alway pairs of elements (i and i+1).
I want to do this 3 times. The pairs would look like this:

```
a[0] and a[1], a[1] and a[2], a[2] and a[3]
```

How can i solve this?
Thanks

Comment: I refuse to even *think* about answering any question that tortures the English language so. Suggest you, at a minimum, capitalise the starts of sentences and personal pronouns, and steer clear of non-words like "wanna" :-)

Comment: @derick - did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If processing 3 times i.e. processing 4 elements in one iteration is mandatory then you should check if the array has at least 4 elements to start with.

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 3; i++) {
      a[i] = 0; // do something 
      a[i+1] = 0; // do something
      a[i+2] = 0; // do something
      a[i+3] = 0; // do something
    }
```

Basically you stop for loop the moment you reach 4th last element.

Here you will be processing elements in the middle of the array more than the elements on either side of middle of array.

If you want each element to be processed only once then increment i by 4 in for loop to ensure each element is processes only once.

Requirements are not clear so suggesting different options, you need to try them in debug mode so you learn it better and implement better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop

```
for(let i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
  a[i] = "modify";
  a[i + 1] = "modify";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a little recursion and nice es6 syntax to do this:

```js
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

const pairValues = (arr, pos = 0, newArr = []) => {
  // check if indexing is out of the bounds of the array
  if (arr[pos + 1] === undefined) {
    return newArr
  }
  newArr.push([arr[pos], arr[pos + 1]])
  // recursively call pairValues function
  return pairValues(arr, pos + 1, newArr)
}
// log result
console.log(pairValues(myArr)) // [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]
```